# How can I match two url patterns in a .htaccess file?

Tags: regex, .htaccess

I need your help. I've this two URLs:

- https://example.com/shop/product-category/langzeitvermietung/testvermietung/
- https://example.com/product-category/langzeitvermietung/

And I want to match both URLs in one regex in my .htaccess file:

```
SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI ^/product-category/langzeitvermietung/ SECURED
```

but somehow it's ignoring the first URL with the shop prefix. Does anyone has an idea how I need to change my regex to get this also matched?

I've tried out the following non-working examples:

```
SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI ^*/product-category/langzeitvermietung/ SECURED
SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI ^(*)/product-category/langzeitvermietung/ SECURED
SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI ^./product-category/langzeitvermietung/ SECURED
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the ^
If I leave that out, it works for me.

Try:

```
SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI /product-category/langzeitvermietung/ SECURED
```